# Store value or infer from another data?

Tags: sql, database, data-structures

I'm working on a finance application where people can send money through it.

Each user can deposit their money in our service and they can send money from their balance to another people. 
This two transaction will affect the amount of their balance in our application.

I'm wondering, what is the best way to get the value of a user's balance. Should I just store the value directly in a column, and change it whenever there is a transaction made by the user, or should I just infer the balance value from all of the transaction that a user made.

The cons for each method that I already think of are:

- Store the value directly:

  - Data consistency: Value difference may happen when one data is saved successfully but another data is not
- Infer from another data:

  - Slower(?): Whenever I want to get the value of the balance, I have to query all of the transaction data and get the sum of it. A lot of function in my application require you to know the value of a user's balance, so maybe this kind of query will be done a lot. And there is also a concern when the user's transaction data has became large.

I built my application using PHP and MySQL, and Yii2 framework.

What do you think the best method to this kind of problem, that while efficient, but also can keep the data integrity and have no problem with a lot of data in the future?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two.

Either:

- Store the value
- Use transactions to make sure no partial results are ever persisted
- Schedule a regular (daily?) task that will verify the consistency using last verified consistent value and the increments

Or:

- Store yesterday's value
- Compute the current value fro yesterday's value and increments
- Schedule a daily task that will update the stored value

Comment: Suppose it is a banking application where some corporate customer has an account. Means thousands of transactions per day. Hence, for computing balance for that customer does it will not slower down the performance. As summing all values for all the transactions each time a transaction is made.

Comment: It largely depends on the expected usage pattern. For a traditional bank, where transactions would come in and out in a batch once a day (during the night), the natural approach is to process the batch and update the balance. If you have a more real-time use case, it's probably better to just count the balance once when updated and then check it again during regular consistency checks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the very late reply from me. The usage pattern for my application is more to  the real-time use case. So I think I'll be using your first approach: store the value, use transaction, and create a regular consitency checking. I'll also implement row locking as suggested by @FallAndLearn .
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Consider first approach.

If db is `Mysql`, You could use the `table-locking (or row-locking)` abilities of MySQL. Use InnoDB tables on your MySQL instance otherwise your system won't be fully ACID-compilant, meaning you won't get the atomicity nature you need.